# can you pass array into django url without passing in path

Tags: python, django, django-urls

say I have a url I want to pass data to like this:

```
{% url 'video_form' {'text': 'text', 'file': video.file, 'image': image} %}
```

and get it like this:

```
def video_form(request):
    print(text)
    print(file.url)
    print(image.url)
```

kind of like POST instead of GET. Can I pass the values in the backend instead of the url like this:

```
path('video_form/<str:text>/', views.video_form, name='video_form')
```

which would not let me pass text inputs in them.

Comment: You say "_kind of like POST instead of GET_". Then why don't you make a POST request then?

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat I’m trying too but it’s hard because I can’t use a form. I’m on heroku and what I’m doing by pass 30s timeout with a form. I’ve been trying to do other things like use Ajax to make a post request in the frontend. Working on it right now.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no. I had to pass the data in the url as a string to another view that uses that information to continue the process in a two step form.